# Test react components with jest and enzyme and css modules

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, enzyme, css-modules

I have a project which was created using create react app.
Lets say I have a simple component like this -

```
import React from 'react';

import React, { useState } from "react";

function Example() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0);
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setData(data + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="button" onClick={onClickHandler}>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I will test the component like this -

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Example from "./Example";

it("example test", () => {
  const wrraper = shallow(<Example />);
  wrraper.find(".button").simulate("click");
  expect("test somethig");
});
```

If I will use styles.module like this -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

function Example() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0);
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setData(data + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.button} onClick={onClickHandler}>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I will not be able to find and element in the test using ".button" anymore, since webpack will add a hash to my class name when I am using css modules.
So how can I test react compoennt while using css modules? Only by adding an Id to the element?
It fills wrong to change my code so I will be able to test it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternative selectors, which you can find [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html). That said, when working with (s)css modules, I tend to lean on the element position within the component:

`wrapper.find("div").first()` will select the first `div` element within the component heirarchy (or in your example, it'll select the div with the "styles.button" className).

Another alternative is to use [template literals](https://css-tricks.com/template-literals/#article-header-id-1). With the example below, I essentially created an escape hatch to select `.some-classname`:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { button } from "./styles.module.scss";

function Example() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0);
  const onClickHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setData(prevSate => prevState + 1);
  }, [setData]);

  return (
    <div className={`${button} some-classname`} onClick={onClickHandler}>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

And lastly, you can use a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) -- like `data-test-id` (which is becoming more popular because of [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library)) to create a simple static selector that can be removed with an additional babel plugin for production builds).

Answer (score -3):

I'm kinda late to the party but I was wondering this myself. You just have to import your scss module into your test file, like this :

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Example from "./Example";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss

it("example test", () => {
  const wrraper = shallow(<Example />);
  wraper.find(`.${styles.button}`).simulate("click");
  expect("test somethig");
});
```